# How to generate nested expression?

Tags: function-construction, expression-construction, functional-style

I've found some related questions, but nothing has really helped me to do what I want to do.

Given a list of variables `L` and a parameter `b`:

```
L = {M1,M2,M3,M4};

b = 1;
```

How can I get the following expression:

```
MyExpression = M1(M2(M3(M4+1)+1)+1)+b;
```

I'm looking for some function `MyFunction[L,b]:=`, that would output such expression.

I need to be able to generate the expression for any number of `M's` (any length of `L`), and where `b` is some integer. I've tried using `Fold` and `FoldList` with no success, in particular, I don't see a way to incorporate a given `b` in the outer "layer" of the expression.

Thanks!

Comment: This perhaps: `Fold[# #2 + 1 &, 1, Reverse[L]] - 1 + b`

Comment: Or this `Plus @@ FoldList[Times, L] + b // HornerForm`